# Array inside array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, jagged-arrays

If `n=4` for example, How to create an array like this in MATLAB?

```
[[0] [0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]]
```

Is there a way to create an array inside a `for` loop, for example ?
This is what I want to achieve (I know it's wrong code):

```
for i=1:n
   table(i)=zeros(i);
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to hold your numeric vectors. Cell arrays are used in Matlab when the contents of each cell are of different size or type.

Additional comments:

- I'm renaming your variable `i` to `k`, to avoid shadowing the imaginary unit.
- I'm also renaming your variable `table` to `t`, to avoid shadowing the `table` function.
- `zeros(k)` gives a `k`x`k` matrix of zeros. To obtain a row vector of zeros use `zeros(1,k)`.
- It's better to preallocate the cell array to improve speed.

Taking the above into account, the code is:

```
n = 4;
t = cell(1,n); %// preallocate: 1xn cell array of empty cells
for k = 1:n
   t{k} = zeros(1,k);
end
```

This gives:

```
>> celldisp(t)
t{1} =
     0
t{2} =
     0     0
t{3} =
     0     0     0
t{4} =
     0     0     0     0
```

Equivalently, you could replace the `for` loop by the more compact [`arrayfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
result = arrayfun(@(k) zeros(1,k), 1:n, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

Comment: arrayfun would give a nice one line answer. :)

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Good idea! I've added that